# SQL query returning "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Tags: mysql, distinct, mysql-error-1241

I'm currently working on a query which will have all rows from one table, but only limited information from the other.

I've tried working with this query:

```
SELECT `t`.`uid`, `t`.`cid`, `t`.`id` FROM `tracking` as `t`
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(`p`.`id`, `p`.`firstname`, `p`.`lastname`, `p`.`company`) FROM `publishers` as `p`) as `p`
ON `p`.id = `t`.uid
```

However, I get the error as in the topic heading.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit:

**Structure on tracking:** id int(11) primary ai, cid int(11), uid int(11).

**Structure on publishers:** id int(11) primary ai, firstname varcher(60), lastname varchar(60), company varchar(100).

**Sample:**
publisher
id 1, firstname NIKOLAJ, lastname JEPSEN, company APECHO
id 6, firstname ROBERT, lastname SCOTT, company FLAPJACK LTD

tracking
id 1, cid 1, uid 1;
id 2, cid 1, uid 6;
id 3, cid 3, uid 1

Comment: Please provide the table structures and some sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely no two publishers can share the same id, firstname, lastname, and company!!!

```
SELECT t.uid
     , t.cid
     , t.id 
  FROM tracking t
  JOIN publishers p
    ON p.id = t.uid;
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. And the return is also was is intended by doing as you just showed. However, the query has to two things: First is to track (a link in this case). Second, it has to show other publishers using the same campaign. Tried to show you in the layout: http://i.imgur.com/PFnOZVh.png

Comment: If you want to show information from the publishers table then you have to include that in the select clause!

Comment: But there comes the distinct part. I only informatin from the publishers table once. Do I really have to make yet another query for ths to happen?

Comment: I don't understand. Surely every row in `tracking` has a corresponding row in `publishers`. I think we need to see DDL's.

Comment: Each row in the tracking table will count as one click on a publishers' link. Therefore, to each row, there's also publisher information (here comes the uid, user-id - publisher id). Now, I need to track all the clicks on the publishers' link, and at the same time, check which publisher's running the same link. - Does it make any sense?

Comment: No. Provide DDLs (CREATE and INSERT statements) for all relevant tables, including enough data to be properly representative of the problem, and the desired result set - or put up an sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT(`p`.`id`, `p`.`firstname`, `p`.`lastname`, `p`.`company`)

is the problem.  Drop the parenthesis:

```
SELECT `t`.`uid`, `t`.`cid`, `t`.`id` FROM `tracking` as `t`
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `p`.`id`, `p`.`firstname`, `p`.`lastname`, `p`.`company` FROM `publishers` as `p`) as `p`
ON `p`.id = `t`.uid
```

That should allow the query to work... however, if you have to use distinct for this, there might be something else wrong with your data structure or query.

Comment: I believe you're absolutely right. What I wanted was to both get the tracking in general, and also show which publishers who's running the campaign. http://i.imgur.com/PFnOZVh.png. This is why I thought I actually got the firstname, lastname and company for each publisher from running this query. I believe I might have some reading up to do.